# Why does Magento use 2 cookies per session?

Tags: security, zend-framework, cookies, magento, privacy

For data security and privacy reasons I want to know why Magento uses two cookies for one frontend session.

All I know is that one of them is being set in `Mage_Core_Model_Cookie::set(..)` and the other one in `Zend_Session::expireSessionCookie()`, but still I can't seem to figure out what they are used for.

I just can't think of any reason why one would need a second cookie for the same domain.

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting..

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty odd to downvote this question with no comment. Seemed like a pretty decent question to me.

Comment: I see no problem with the question.  Can I ask why you are concerned about it for security reasons?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know it exactly as I only have to fill out a catalog of security and privacy-related question for some other department.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this by reversing the order of the `session_start()` call and the statement that sets the cookie in `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start(..)`. Those two lines now look like this:

```
$cookie->set(session_name(), $this->getSessionId());
session_start();
```

It now only creates one single cookie and it does not seem to have any side-effects.

BTW: The other cookie was not created in Zend_Session as I assumed, but instead both of them came from `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start(..)`.

Comment: Nice solution, but be careful editing the core files.  You should (at least) create a copy in the `app/code/local` file hierarchy rather than directly editing the core.  This should minimise breakage for upgrades/patches.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in fact I actually did it this way. I don't like having to hack core files, but in cases like this I guess one just doesn't stand a chance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to call this one vestigial code. Varien relies heavily on the Zend Framework as the underpinning for Magento, so many of the classes (Zend_Session for instance) are used as parent classes for Magento implementations.

The Varien-set cookie labeled "frontend" is namespaced for the section of the site you visit (e.g. you will have a separate "admin" cookie if you log in through the backend), whereas the Zend cookie appears to be global.

Also note that I was able to delete the Zend cookie without any apparent deleterious effects (my login session and cart remained accessible, and the cookie was not immediately replaced).

Comment: Thanks! I just tried to delete the second cookie as well and it seems as if it is not needed at all. So I might be able to remove the this cookie completely without any side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

That is interesting. I just checked on an install of enterprise edition and only "PHPSESSIONID" is set, "frontend" and "admin" are missing even when logged into both. Perhaps this is something still actively being developed.