# Double Set-Cookie in Magento, leading to a login issue for some users

Tags: magento, cookies, authentication

We have a Magento application which is issuing dual Set-Cookie's . Here are the headers:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2012 21:04:28 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
  Set-Cookie: frontend=iti6c00cdm6cc79hfl1pl9pq52; expires=Wed, 18-Apr-2012 22:04:28 GMT; path=/
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  Pragma: no-cache
  Set-Cookie: frontend=iti6c00cdm6cc79hfl1pl9pq52; expires=Wed, 18-Apr-2012 22:04:28 GMT; path=/; domain=**example.com**
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In some circumstances, after logging in the second cookie is set to frontend=deleted . From my reading it appears that two frontend= cookies are not a "problem", this is standard Magento behaviour. From my reading of the spec, the second frontend= cookie will overwrite the first if their scope/spec is the same.

Any ideas where we can start digging in to this problem to see why the second frontend= cookie does not behave like the first?

Magento version is enterprise edition of ver. 1.9.0.0

Related Questions

- [Why does Magento use 2 cookies per session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924093/why-does-magento-use-2-cookies-per-session)
- [Magento Cookies Changing Prevent Frontend Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948638/magento-cookies-changing-prevent-frontend-login)

Comment: What is the behavior for the user? Redirected back to login? are you using Lightspeed or other caching?

Comment: I've got a similar issues, where the cookie is set twice. This seems to stem from the fact that lightspeed.php creates a cookie when there is none. This happens outside of the Magento framework, which results in the cookie set twice.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the Session validation checks fail - the cookie will then be cleared with the "deleted" value and a expiration date in the past:

The following information will be checked by Magento for validating a session:

- The client IP address that is connecting to the server
- The "Via" HTTP-Header
- The "X-Forwarded-For" Header
- The "User-Agent" Header

If one (or more) of these informations changes during the requests for the same Session ID, the session will be Discarted, the Cookie will be cleared in the way as described and the Server will send a Redirect header to the Homepage.

You can change which Information to validate in the Magento Admin-Panel by going to System > Configuration > Web. But you should **never** turn off all checks since this will allow session hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to override fronten cookie... if so better try to first destroy the cookie and then reset it by using Magento method

Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('frontend', $session->getCustomer()->getId(), 100000*24*3600);